# Как сделать полукруглый блок с таким же содержимым?

Tags: css3, jquery, javascript, html, вёрстка

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Линию картинкой - и будет счастье:
http://jsfiddle.net/826gceeo/10/

---

Версия 2
http://jsfiddle.net/826gceeo/18/

Comment: А как высчитывать длину картинки?

Comment: Длина дуги окружности, координаты начала и конца известны, угол в цикле просумировать. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8

Comment: Посмотрите версию 2, вам достаточно будет сделать картинку линии(скажем 3 пикселя в ширину), а дальше она просто будет дублироваться, в итоге получится целая линия

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, тебе надо искать что-то наподобие этого - http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: Или [D3.js](http://d3js.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Не успел CSS3 войти в нашу жизнь целиком и полностью, от него уже требуют следующих фишек.

В вашем случае для сидушек подойдет обыкновенный трансформ rotate, так как на длине сидушки искривление незаметно.
Для Амфитеатров можно использовать просто картинку с imageMap.
Для сцены - аналогично: полупрозрачную картинку или оооочень большой радиус скругления уголка с градиентным фоном.

Comment: То есть для каждой сидушки отдельно, что ли, писать трансформ rotate, и как еще сделать подсветку для каждой линии?

Comment: для каждой сидушки отдельно что ли писать трансформ rotate// Да. Но не руками, а в функции. В вашем случае достаточно обычной окружности для определения угла. В реальности это скорее всего эллипс с разными диаметрами.  
Подсветка - это оранжевый лазер? Самое простое - картинка. Сложнее - нарисовать эту кривуляку в Canvas.

Comment: оранжевый лазер -да это картинка

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp  
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp  
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp

Comment: Попробуйте поискать на специализированных сайтах, если сроки поджимают и необходимо сделать именно так.

N.B. Быстрее и проще всего все-таки реализовать через image map. Получится статично, но гарантированно работоспособно.

Comment: в данном случае,что вы подразумевате под словом статичный?

Comment: Статично - довольно трудно генерить под разные залы. Придется перерисовывать картинку.

Comment: Попробуйте sass / less / stylus, через пару часов знакомства еще не такое количество трансформов будете уметь делать.